# How to add multiple searchJoin conditions for Laravel's prettus/l5-repository

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I am trying to pass query params to generate the sql query like this:

```
select * from table_name 
where key_1 = 'qwe'
AND  
(
key_2 = 'zxc' 
OR key_3 = 'lxc'
OR key_4 = 'poi'
)
```

I have tried with

```
/api/records?search=key_1:qwe&searchJoin=and;key_2:zxc;key_3:lxc;key_4:poi&searchJoin=or
```

but this seems to return all data with `key_1 = que` regardless of the key_2, key_3 and key_4 params. So, I assume the searchJoin=OR is only used here.

How can I derive the desired query?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for replying so late, but I had the same question and found yours. I had to develop a new Criteria extending the RequestCriteria provided by Prettus and pushing it to my repository.

I developed it on a way that I could use my custom RequestCriteria and the base RequestCriteria at the same time, but it is up to you.

Basically, I copied most of the apply function code to my class and removed some parts that I believe that would not be useful.

My requests can have this format, for example:

- url?search=name:Test&searchJoin=and&searchGroup[0][search]=group_id:1;subgroup_id:2&searchGroup[1]